# How can I read the last ID record added on a form?

Tags: asp.net

```
 If Session("") = 0 Then
```

**here i want to read the last Id that was added on an specific form**

```
 If reader.HasRows Then
   Do While reader.Read()
```

etc.

Comment: how's the last id added to your form?   are those ids added in a dynamic fashion?  also u know the name of the control that holds your ID record?

Comment: Hey @erins, welcome to SO. It's not clear what you'd like to do. Please be more specific about your problem and provide more details about those Ids.

Comment: edit question and add, what you want, and what have you tried??

Comment: Formatted code as code, remove tag from the title

Comment: Something like var loop = true;
    while (loop)
    {
        //1. Here retrive values you need e.g. var myvar = reader.GetBoolean(0);
        loop = reader.Read();
        if (!loop)
        {
            //You are on the last record. Use values read in 1.
            //Do some exceptions
        }
        else {
            //You are not on the last record.
            //Process values read in 1., e.g. myvar
        }
    }

Comment: I am doing a ticket form and I have session for this.. Session = 0 when ticket is in compilation and session=1 when ticket is open..Now I add some people when session is 0 and send their a message, now i want that when i forget to add one peope for eg  and session goes 1 to send the message only at the new ones not at the people i add before..
        'If Session("IDStatoTicket") = 1 
"here i want to read only the ID of new people that i add not before

Answer (score 0):

Be honest, this code really reads the last id from your reader (assuming SqlDataReader and the value is always integer).  If it's a form (assuming HTML form), it would be Request.Form.

```
Dim yourIdFieldName As String = "ID"
Dim myLastId as Integer

If reader.HasRows Then
    Do While reader.Read()
        myLastId= Convert.ToInt32(reader.Item(yourIdFieldName))
    Loop
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get last record like this.You need to track it.

```
If reader.Read() Then
Dim [loop] = True
While [loop]
    '1. Here retrive values you need e.g. var myvar = reader.GetBoolean(0);
    [loop] = reader.Read()
            'You are on the last record. Use values .

    If Not [loop] Then
            'You are not on the last record.                
    Else
    End If
End While
```